# How to insert the checkbox value in database using ajax...... i am trying below code not not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

form:

```
<?php     foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM `company_details` WHERE id='$userid' LIMIT 1 ") as $edit) { 
            echo '<form class="form-horizontal" id="productdetail_form" name="productdetail_form"  method="post" style="padding:20px 0;">
                <input type="hidden" name="productdetail_formhide" id="productdetail_formhide" value="productdetail_formhide"/>
                 <input type="hidden" name="productdetail_city" id="productdetail_city" value="'.$edit['city'].'">
                  <input type="hidden" name="cid" id="cid" value="'.$userid.'">
                    <input type="hidden" name="productdetail_cname" id="productdetail_cname" value="'.$edit['comp_name'].'">';}?>
                    <h2>Manufacture</h2>

                <div class="row"><div class="col-sm-4" >
                 <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Water Sports Equipment" />Water Sports Equipment
    </label><br/>

    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" class="check"  id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Adventure Sports" />Adventure Sports
    </label><br/>
    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Billiard/Snooker/polls"/>Billiard/Snooker/polls
    </label><br/>  
    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Gym Fitness Equipment" >Gym Fitness Equipment
    </label><br/>
    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Medal Trophy"  >Medal Trophy
    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Playground Equipment" >Playground Equipment
    </label><br/>
    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Sports Bags" >Sports Bags
    </label><br/>
    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Sports Apprarels" >Sports Apprarels
    </label><br/>
    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Sports Bikes / Cycles" >Sports Bikes / Cycles
    </label><br/>
    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Sports Goods" >Sports Goods
    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
               <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Sports Nutrition" >Sports Nutrition
    </label><br/>
    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Sports Wear Fabric">Sports Wear Fabric
    </label><br/>
    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Sports Flooring" >Sports Flooring
    </label><br/>
    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Sports Shoes">Sports Shoes
    </label><br/>
    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Sports Raw Materials" >Sports Raw Materials
    </label></br>
    <div class="form-group">
<label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
<div class="col-sm-10 text-center">
<input type="submit" id="productdetail_submit" name="productdetail_submit" value="Submit Product Details" class="btn btn-success">

</div>
</div>
                </div>
                </div>

             </form> 

?>

$( "#productdetail_form" ).submit(function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
var productdetail_formhide = $("#productdetail_formhide").val();
var productdetail_cid = $("#cid").val();
var productdetail_cname = $("#productdetail_cname").val();
var Basic_Amenities= new Array(); 
          var Basic_Amenities = new Array();
        $("#manufacture :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
           Basic_Amenities.push($(this).val());
        });
var productdetail_city = $("#productdetail_city").val();
var manufacture = $("a[name=tab1]").data("index");
$("#productdetail_form").empty();
alert(Basic_Amenities);
alert(manufacture);
$("#productdetail_form").prepend('<div id="productdetail" style="color:red;">Submitting data..... Please Wait.. </div>');
  $.post("merchant/edit_ajax.php",
  {
    productdetail_formhide:productdetail_formhide,
    productdetail_cid:productdetail_cid,
    productdetail_cname:productdetail_cname,
    Basic_Amenities:Basic_Amenities,
    productdetail_city:productdetail_city,
    manufacture:manufacture,     
     },
  function(data,status){

$("#productdetail").hide();
$("#productdetail_form").prepend(data);
    });

});
```

Below code is on ajax.php

```
//for manufactures where cid='$userid'  AND categories='Manufaturers'
if(isset($_POST['productdetail_formhide'])=='productdetail_formhide'){  
$q = $db->prepare("UPDATE `business_category` SET cid=:cid, comp_name=:comp_name, categories=:categories, subcategories=:subcategories, city=:city ,activation='0' WHERE cid='$userid'  AND categories='Manufaturers'");
            foreach($_POST['Basic_Amenities'] as $basic){
$q->execute(array(':cid'=>$_POST['cid'].'',
                  ':comp_name'=>$_POST['productdetail_cname'].'',
                  ':categories'=>$_POST['manufacture'].'',
                  ':subcategories'=>$basic.'',
                  ':city'=>$_POST['productdetail_city'].''));
            }
 if($q==true){
    echo '<div align="center" >
    <div style="color:green;"> Thank You ..Your details submitted sucessfully <br> Your Profile Will Be Activated Soon ..!!</div>
    </div>';
    exit();
    } 
    else{
        echo '<div style="color:red;">business details not submitted</div>';
        }

        }
```

Comment: what part is not working?  i suggest in chrome dev tools -> network tab, watch the ajax call and check what is posted and returned. also your if statement at the start of your ajax.php looks questionable.

Comment: How means 'not working'? You put many lines of your code, try to locate the problem better.

Comment: Please explain your code and also explain what check box is being used to get data from screen to db in which fields.

Comment: my submit button is not working

Answer (score 0):

script tag was missing. Try this.

```
 <?php     foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM `company_details` WHERE id='$userid' LIMIT 1 ") as $edit) { 
            echo '<form class="form-horizontal" id="productdetail_form" name="productdetail_form"  method="post" style="padding:20px 0;">
                <input type="hidden" name="productdetail_formhide" id="productdetail_formhide" value="productdetail_formhide"/>
                 <input type="hidden" name="productdetail_city" id="productdetail_city" value="'.$edit['city'].'">
                  <input type="hidden" name="cid" id="cid" value="'.$userid.'">
                    <input type="hidden" name="productdetail_cname" id="productdetail_cname" value="'.$edit['comp_name'].'">';}?>
                    <h2>Manufacture</h2>

                <div class="row"><div class="col-sm-4" >
                 <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Water Sports Equipment" />Water Sports Equipment
    </label><br/>

    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" class="check"  id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Adventure Sports" />Adventure Sports
    </label><br/>
    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Billiard/Snooker/polls"/>Billiard/Snooker/polls
    </label><br/>  
    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Gym Fitness Equipment" >Gym Fitness Equipment
    </label><br/>
    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Medal Trophy"  >Medal Trophy
    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Playground Equipment" >Playground Equipment
    </label><br/>
    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Sports Bags" >Sports Bags
    </label><br/>
    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Sports Apprarels" >Sports Apprarels
    </label><br/>
    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Sports Bikes / Cycles" >Sports Bikes / Cycles
    </label><br/>
    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Sports Goods" >Sports Goods
    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
               <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Sports Nutrition" >Sports Nutrition
    </label><br/>
    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Sports Wear Fabric">Sports Wear Fabric
    </label><br/>
    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Sports Flooring" >Sports Flooring
    </label><br/>
    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Sports Shoes">Sports Shoes
    </label><br/>
    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Basic_Amenities" name="Basic_Amenities[]" value="Sports Raw Materials" >Sports Raw Materials
    </label></br>
    <div class="form-group">
<label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
<div class="col-sm-10 text-center">
<input type="submit" id="productdetail_submit" name="productdetail_submit" value="Submit Product Details" class="btn btn-success">

</div>
</div>
                </div>
                </div>

             </form> 

<script>

$( "#productdetail_form" ).submit(function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
var productdetail_formhide = $("#productdetail_formhide").val();
var productdetail_cid = $("#cid").val();
var productdetail_cname = $("#productdetail_cname").val();
var Basic_Amenities= new Array(); 
          var Basic_Amenities = new Array();
        $("#manufacture :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
           Basic_Amenities.push($(this).val());
        });
var productdetail_city = $("#productdetail_city").val();
var manufacture = $("a[name=tab1]").data("index");
$("#productdetail_form").empty();
alert(Basic_Amenities);
alert(manufacture);
$("#productdetail_form").prepend('<div id="productdetail" style="color:red;">Submitting data..... Please Wait.. </div>');
  $.post("merchant/edit_ajax.php",
  {
    productdetail_formhide:productdetail_formhide,
    productdetail_cid:productdetail_cid,
    productdetail_cname:productdetail_cname,
    Basic_Amenities:Basic_Amenities,
    productdetail_city:productdetail_city,
    manufacture:manufacture,     
     },
  function(data,status){

$("#productdetail").hide();
$("#productdetail_form").prepend(data);
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: i have already included script in my code main thing that is submit is not working .............